# HTTP ERROR 404 when reload page

Tags: angular, azure, web, http-status-code-404, blogs

I have a problem. I' ve written the code and start it in my local server.
 Everything work nice, but when I push it to Azure it was broken.

Problem: When I go to link it works normal, but when I reload it give me error 404.

Also When I write this everything work, but i don't like # in my URL

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
```

With this it doesn't work

```
{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
```

app.module.ts

```
// NG Core
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 
import { AppRouterRoutingModule } from './app-router/app-router-routing.module';
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF
} from '@angular/common'; 


// Components
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroComponent } from './components/hero/hero.component';
import { ListblogComponent } from './components/listblog/listblog.component';
import { BlognavbarComponent } from './components/blognavbar/blognavbar.component';
import { SoloblogComponent } from './components/soloblog/soloblog.component';
import { MdToHtmlPipe } from './services/pipe/md-to-html.pipe';


// Dependencys
import { InlineSVGModule } from 'ng-inline-svg';
import { SwiperModule } from 'angular2-useful-swiper';
import { Ng2PageScrollModule } from 'ng2-page-scroll';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroComponent,
    ListblogComponent,
    BlognavbarComponent,
    SoloblogComponent,
    MdToHtmlPipe,
  ],
  imports: [ 
    NgbModule.forRoot(), 
    RouterModule.forRoot([]),
    AppRouterRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SwiperModule,
    InlineSVGModule,
    Ng2PageScrollModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule,
  ],
  providers: [ ContentfulService, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy} ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-router-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../components/home/home.component';
import { TeamComponent } from '../components/team/team.component';
import { ListblogComponent } from '../components/listblog/listblog.component';
import { SoloblogComponent } from '../components/soloblog/soloblog.component';
import {  
  PlatformLocation,  
  Location,  
  LocationStrategy,  
  HashLocationStrategy,  
  PathLocationStrategy,  
  APP_BASE_HREF
} from '@angular/common'; 


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: "",
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: "blog",
    component: ListblogComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: "team",
    component: TeamComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: "blog/:id",
    component: SoloblogComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRouterRoutingModule { }
```

In index.html I have

```
 <base href="/" />
```

You can try it yourself. Go to http://beta-rev.azurewebsites.net/ after click "Blog" button in the header. You should go to blog, but if you reload page you'll see the error.

In advance, thanks for help!

Solve

I've past web.config into my folder src

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMaxAge="30.00:00:00" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge"/>
      <!-- use utf-8 encoding for anything served text/plain or text/html -->
      <!-- in the case of .html files; if you AJAX load html files (i.e. in angular) then remove these two lines. -->
      <remove fileExtension=".html"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".html" mimeType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".css"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".css" mimeType="text/css"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".js"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".json"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".rss"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".rss" mimeType="application/rss+xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".xml"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xml" mimeType="application/xml; charset=UTF-8"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".map"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".map" mimeType="application/json" />
      <!-- HTML5 Audio/Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".mp3"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp3" mimeType="audio/mpeg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".mp4"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ogg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogg" mimeType="audio/ogg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ogv"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ogv" mimeType="video/ogg"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webm"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webm" mimeType="video/webm"/>
      <!-- Proper svg serving. Required for svg webfonts on iPad -->
      <remove fileExtension=".svg"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".svgz"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svgz" mimeType="image/svg+xml"/>
      <!-- HTML4 Web font mime types -->
      <!-- Remove default IIS mime type for .eot which is application/octet-stream -->
      <remove fileExtension=".eot"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".ttc"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttc" mimeType="application/x-font-ttf"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".otf"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="font/opentype"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".crx"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".crx" mimeType="application/x-chrome-extension"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".xpi"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".xpi" mimeType="application/x-xpinstall"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".safariextz"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".safariextz" mimeType="application/octet-stream"/>
      <!-- Flash Video mime types-->
      <remove fileExtension=".flv"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".flv" mimeType="video/x-flv"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".f4v"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".f4v" mimeType="video/mp4"/>
      <!-- Assorted types -->
      <remove fileExtension=".ico"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ico" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webp" mimeType="image/webp"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".htc"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".htc" mimeType="text/x-component"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".vcf"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".vcf" mimeType="text/x-vcard"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".torrent"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".torrent" mimeType="application/x-bittorrent"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".cur"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".cur" mimeType="image/x-icon"/>
      <remove fileExtension=".webapp"/>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".webapp" mimeType="application/x-web-app-manifest+json; charset=UTF-8"/>
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="./index.html" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also into angular.json

```
"build": {
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/web.config"          
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably missing rewrite rules. Here an example web.config that should work for you:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff"/>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="font/woff2" />
     </staticContent>

      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

See also: [Web.config for hosting an Angular application on Azure Web App](https://about-azure.com/2018/02/06/web-config-for-hosting-an-angular-application-on-azure-web-app/)

Comment: I've created a file Web.config in my folder with this code and it's worked

Answer (score 2):

If you are hosting in azure web app(ubuntu). Please use the below start up command.

```
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/build --no-daemon --spa
```

Using --spa option pm2 will automatically redirect all queries to the index.html and then react router will do its magic.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has its own routing mechanism. For it to work you need to always redirect to your `index.html`. See: https://css-tricks.com/redirect-web-page/ how to. I personally redirect urls using the .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

For those that might wonder the simplest solution is to do it within your Angular - entry point (usually is app.componnets.ts/js)

On NgOnInt to reload on refresh
call --> this.router.navigate(['']);
where router is the Router from '@angular/router';